# ORA-39358: Export dump file version 12.2.0 not compatible with target version 12.1.0.2.0

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have upgraded my ORACLE local from 12.1.0.2.0 to 12.2.0.1.0, and I have dump exported from 12.2.0.1.0, and I am importing that dump by `impdp` command, but it showing old target ORACLE version with following error

```
ORA-39358: Export dump file version 12.2.0 not compatible with target version 12.1.0.2.0
```

I have tried to execute `impdp` command as administrator, It showing the correct database connected to, but the issue is same

log file of `impdp`:

```
;;; 
Import: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Jun 12 15:41:17 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
Master table "NEW_DB"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
ORA-39358: Export dump file version 12.2.0 not compatible with target version 12.1.0.2.0
Job "NEW_DB"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at Wed Jun 12 15:41:26 2019 elapsed 0 00:00:07
Job "NEW_DB"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at Wed Jun 12 15:41:27 2019 elapsed 0 00:00:08
```

Comment: the error obvious, isn't it? ( The DB doesn't permit to import backwards ).

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan , yes, but I recently have upgraded to required version 12.2.0.1.0, I don't know why it is still picking old version while import.

Comment: And the issue I had was where the target database initialization variable `compatible` was set to `12.2.0.1.0` in my `19.15.0.0.0` target database.  Yes I know that is bad news!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start you export with parameter VERSION=12.1. This will make the export compatible with your target 12.1 database.

```
expdp system@std12c VERSION=12.1 schemas=...
```

You might run into some problems if your source database uses options not yet available in your target database. For example:

```
Warning: Oracle Data Pump is exporting from a database that supports long identifiers to a version that does not support long identifiers
```

Comment: The problem is I can't export again, That's why I have upgraded my oracle from(12.1.0.1.0) to required version (Upper version 12.2.0.1.0)

Comment: I see, you are connected to 12.2 but it still complains about 12.1. Strange. Maybe you missed some upgrade steps.

Comment: yup, Its strange, I got the success message while up gradation(Upgrade Results).
and I am able to connect and can work on existing db users.